# MS Access: Different formulas for different fields in the same column

Tags: ms-access, field, formula, calculated-field

I understand that I can add a table column of type "Calculated Field". However, after building an expression/formula, it is applied to the entire column. Is there a way to have a different formula for fields in the same column but different rows?

Answer (score 1):

As I know, it's not possible, the formula always applied to all rows in the column. As a workaround you can build your formula in order to analyse the data in the row and calculate accordingly.

In addition I would recommend to do not use calculated columns in the table, you will have more problems than advantages. Use queries instead.

Comment: I see! However, how do I go about building my query so that it updates selective fields? Queries seem to update the entire column as well.

Comment: Quite sure, it can be done using query. Please describe the task you are trying to solve more detailed, just edit original question.